# How do I fix the issue of delayed detection of charging in Plasma5?

Tags: plasma5, battery

I have the latest `Pop!_OS 20.04`. I recently I installed `KDE Plasma` on my machine.

The only thing that has been annoying me is once my battery gets low, and I plug in my charger, KDE takes almost half an hour to detect that. That basically means if I plug in at `10%`, even when my machine is plugged in, KDE will shut the system down.

Note that plug in early or at 20% is not a desired solution.

Comment: What does `sudo acpi -V` return when you *"plug in at 10%"*?

Comment: No idea why it's happening for you.

Comment: You can file a bug report [here](https://bugs.kde.org/).

Comment: I'd also recommend filing a bug report against KDE or Pop!_OS itself.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Yes.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi, consider making an answer. If you are lucky it will achieve score 2 and then the bounty is at least not lost (only to OP). I'd consider the reference to the bug report a decent insight to this question. Or maybe it attracts other answerers and provokes them into making a better one, maybe even with an actual solution. I don't think that OP can or should try to rescue the bounty that way however....

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I have the same problem in KDE Neon Unstable(which has much fresher KDE packages than PopOS! even though it's based on ubuntu 18.04) but in my case the problem is that ```upower``` doesn't get updated when the battery status changes.If I restart the upower via ```sudo service upower restart``` then the output in both the applet and ```upower -d``` becomes correct.In your case which you've reported that the output of **upower** is true , I think it's surely a bug within the applet.But in my case the problem is with the ```upower daemon``` not the applet.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 But I have a solution for you.This file ```/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity``` should contain the correct battery charge percentage regardless of what **upower** or **batteryinformation** applet say.If you run the following command :```zenity --info --text `cat /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity`
``` it will open up a window and show you the correct percentage.You can assign a shortcut to it.Not an answer to your question but it works.

Comment: And if the above path might be different in your system.Just search for ```BAT0/capacity``` via ```find /sys 2>/dev/null | grep "BAT0\/capacity"```.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Again, please consider making an answer. Even if not OP, you might receive upvotes from whoever finds help in your contribution. I do not really know, but maybe even the bounty can still be shifted and I would not mind. I would even make my own bounty and hand it over to you if your answer passes mine in score. Assumnig I get some kind of confirmation that it would not break any rules.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for your suggestion.I'm trying to write a new plasmoid that uses the aforementioned interface and wouldn't have that problem related to **upower**.If it gets done, then I would write an answer with that.

Comment: :-) The goal is now to make a nice Q/A pair. And maybe to get an accept and maybe a bounty to somebody who deserves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an applet for KDE Plasma 5 which shows the battery percentage based on the `/sys` interface (which gets updated instantly and hasn't the delay of **UPower** daemon or the **Battery and Brightness** plasmoid).

`/sys` is in fact an interface for accessing the kernel data structures at runtime.It resides completely on memory and is a useful source of debugging information.The information that we need here is the exact battery percentage:

```
$ tree /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/
.
├── alarm
├── capacity
├── capacity_level
├── cycle_count
├── device -> ../../../PNP0C0A:00
├── energy_full
├── energy_full_design
├── energy_now
├── hwmon1
│   ├── device -> ../../BAT0
│   ├── in0_input
│   ├── name
│   ├── power
│   │   ├── async
│   │   ├── autosuspend_delay_ms
│   │   ├── control
│   │   ├── runtime_active_kids
│   │   ├── runtime_active_time
│   │   ├── runtime_enabled
│   │   ├── runtime_status
│   │   ├── runtime_suspended_time
│   │   └── runtime_usage
│   ├── subsystem -> ../../../../../../../../../../class/hwmon
│   ├── temp1_label
│   ├── temp2_label
│   └── uevent
├── manufacturer
├── model_name
├── power
│   ├── async
│   ├── autosuspend_delay_ms
│   ├── control
│   ├── runtime_active_kids
│   ├── runtime_active_time
│   ├── runtime_enabled
│   ├── runtime_status
│   ├── runtime_suspended_time
│   └── runtime_usage
├── power_now
├── present
├── serial_number
├── status
├── subsystem -> ../../../../../../../../../class/power_supply
├── technology
├── type
├── uevent
├── voltage_min_design
└── voltage_now
```

For example the number that we're looking for resides under this file(in my system):

```
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
```

It shows the correct percentage of the battery (BAT0):

[image]

The responsibility of this plasmoid is to read that number regularly every three seconds.

---

Here's the project repository: https://gitlab.com/P.Mousavi/batperc-indicator
And if you wanted to compile and run it, follow the instructions below:

Install the dependencies(explained in **README.md**) and run:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/P.Mousavi/batperc-indicator.git
cd batperc-indicator
mkdir build
cd build
qmake ../plugin/
make
sudo make install
```

If all goes without any error then you should be able to see the plasmoid **Battery percentage indicator** in the widgets side-bar in KDE Plasma and you can drag-n-drop it from there.

There are a lot of TODOs like changing the color when the percentage goes below a threshold etc.But for now I'm busy :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: It seems you really achieved something there. However, based on my experience on StackOverflow, an answer will not really be considered an answer as long as practically all of the solution is only linked. (I am not presuming familiarity with this sister site, so I am not going to flag. But I think there is a certain risk that others will do so.) If you describe the basic principle of how you achieved the solution directly here, just as a summary, then I expect you will harvest some upvotes. Everybody else in this community, please let me know if I am wrong, e.g. by upvoting as is.... ;-)

Comment: Note, I do see the "based on the /sys interface (which gets updated instantly and hasn't the delay of UPower or the Battery and Brightness plasmoid)." For me that is more of a description *what* it achieves, less of *how*. Maybe that is only because I lack technical knowhow.

Comment: @Yunnosch Your statement about "being considered as an answer" holds true here too.And I updated my post with additional explanations about how it works.But  everything else about that is just implementation detail and I think is inappropriate and off-topic here.However thanks for your feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

(*I am mostly doing this answer to provoke somebody else into making a better one to prevent me from earning the bounty undeservedly. Please make a better one. Please prefer upvoting any other answer than mine. As soon as I notice any answer with actual solution proposals I will happily delete mine. Otherwise let this answer get score 2, so as to at least avoid the frustration for OP that the reputation they lost is at least not completely lost...*)

The discsussion in the comments has shown that there is no obvious mistake on OPs part.
Commenters agree that this is most likely a bug in KDE.

There now is a filed bug report by OP
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=423556#c1

And it seems that the bug has also already been reported just before.

If the question is not closed or deleted, this, the current status of the analysis, is the closest anybody can get to an answer.